# Definition of random variable (measure theoretic)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

My book defines a random variable $X$ as a real measurable function on a probability measure space $(\Omega, F, P)$. My question is as follows: is the probability measure $P$ defined over the elements of $F$, or over the elements of $X(F)$? Or is there no difference?

Comment: @JohnB How could they belong to $F$ when $\Omega\not\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: Roberto, when you write $(\Omega,F,P)$, then $P$ is of course a measure on the measurable space $(\Omega,F)$. So, $P(A)$ is only defined for $A\in F$.

Comment: @JohnB I asked "How, when $\Omega\not\subset\mathbb R$" and you answer "whenever $\Omega=\mathbb R$". Well, dou *you* know the subject? ;-)

Comment: So the answer is...

Comment: @JohnB Seldom have I seen a figure on this platform with such a bad character. I don't regret that "you have no time for me".

Comment: The answer has been told to you several times. $P$ is defined on the elements of $F$.

Comment: So then the probability of getting a particular value of a random variable is the probability of the pre-image of the random variable?

Comment: That's exactly it, Roberto. If $A\subset\mathbb R$ is a Borel set then $P(X\in A)$ means $P(X^{-1}(A))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measure is defined in the measure space, that is, $P$ is a measure in $\Omega$, not in the codomain of $X$.

However the measure $P$ induces a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_X$ in the codomain of $X$ by

$$\mu_X(A):=P(X^{-1}(A))$$

for any Lebesgue measurable set $A\subset\Bbb R$. This induced measure $\mu_X$ defines the distribution of $X$ via $F_X(c):=\mu_X((-\infty, c])$, and so we have that

$$
P(X^{-1}(-\infty,c])=\int_{X^{-1}(-\infty,c]} dP=\int_{(-\infty,c]}d\mu_X
$$

where we generally use the shorthand $P(X\le c):=P(X^{-1}(-\infty,c])=F_X(c)$ to refer to "the probability that $X$ would be equal or less than $c$" and $dF_X:=d\mu_X$ is a common notation for the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure.

When $F_X$ haves a continuous derivative then $dF_X=F_X'(x)\,dx$ where $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ and $f_X:=F'_X$ is called the density of $X$.

I hope you get all clear now.

NOTE: observe that above we require that $X$ is a measurable function, that is, that $X^{-1}(A)\in F$ for any Lebesgue measurable set $A$.