# What does a probability measure say about the distribution of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Given a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$, and a random variable $X:\Omega\to E$ ($E$-valued random variable mapping to measurable space $(E,S)$.

Then the random variable $X$ maps outcomes from $\Omega$ to $E$-values in the measurable space, and, the probability measure $P$ maps events in $F$ to $[0,1]$.

Is it true that generally knowing the probability measure $P$ says nothing about the distribution of $X$, and vice versa, (since the probability of an event says nothing about the probability of specific outcomes in the event)??

i.e. in general you can't find the probability distribution of $X$ given you know the probability measure $P$, and vice versa, right?

Comment: $A\mapsto P\circ X^{-1}(A)$ for $A\in S$ maps $S$ to $[0,1]$ so if you know the measure $P$ and the inverse image of the RV then you know the law/distribution of the RV.

Comment: @ Nap D. Lover Okey, but doesn't that assume that the preimage is an event in the sigma-algebra? What if the preimage is an outcome in the sample space which is not an event in the sigma-algebra?? Can I find the probability then?

Comment: By definition a RV $X: \Omega \to E$, where $(E,S)$ is the target measure space, is $S/\mathscr{F}$ measurable so $X^{-1}(A)\in \mathscr{F}$ for all $A\in S$ hence $P \circ X^{-1}(A)$ is always well defined.

Comment: @ Nap D. Lover So, even though a RV is a mapping from the sample space to  it can ONLY take as input outcomes/events that are in the sigma-algebra on the probability space??

Comment: The random variable $X(\omega)$ is defined on every outcome $\omega\in \Omega$, and takes values in $E$ i.e. $X:\Omega \to E$. The *inverse image* is, since $X$ is measurable, defined on all of $S$, and takes values in $\mathscr{F}$ i.e. $X^{-1}: S\to \mathscr{F}$. Please distinguish the mapping $X$ which is defined on individual outcomes $\omega \in \Omega$ and the mapping $X^{-1}$ which is defined on $S$, the measurable subsets of $E$. Review the definitions carefully.

Comment: For a concrete example, take real valued RVs. The interval $(-\infty, x]$ is a Borel set, so $X^{-1}((-\infty, x])=\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\}$ is in $\mathscr{F}$ since $X$ is $\mathscr{B}/\mathscr{F}$ measurable and hence and has a probability under $P$, etc which we usually write as $P(X\leq x)$ suppressing the $\omega$ notation.

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389737/definition-of-random-variable-measure-theoretic/3389807#3389807)