# Difference between probability function and probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

I read an explanation of a probability measure as: For any set of values it gives the probability the random variable is in that set of values.

If we have a density/mass function: Isn't a probability measure then just the same as integrating/sum the density/mass function over the intervals/values that represent the various events? Where the events of course are the sets found in sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F, P})$.

Comment: yes it is exactly as you say, a probability measure is a mapping from the sigma algebra of events to $[0,1]$. A density function maps $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$

Comment: yes, it is as you said. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389737/definition-of-random-variable-measure-theoretic/3389807#3389807) for other details. In short: a random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to \Bbb R $ and a probability measure $\Pr$ is a positive measure in the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\Pr(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: @ George Dewhirst @ Masacroso Furthermore, is it correct to say that: a probability measure tells you probabilities of events in sigma algebra, and, a density/mass function tells you (same) probabilities of the intervals/values of a random variable defined on the sample space? (i.e. the intervals/values corresponding to the events in the sigma algebra.)